# Paypal Silent Post failing on test account

Tags: api, paypal, transactions

I am doing some development using payflow api I created test only payflow account. (Transaction Process Mode = Test)

My program uses secure token with hosted check out page.
SilentPost enabled.

Using the test credit card #4111111111111111.

But after I submitted the payment, the page was redirected to the URL specified in "Return URL when Silent Post fails" (which I take it as the transaction have failed).

I search the transaction (PNREF# returned to my code) using the paypal manager.  There are 2 transactions.

First transaction -> Result Code = 0, Response Message = Approved , Transaction Type = Sale

Second Transaction -> Reuslt Code = 0, Response Message = Approved, Transaction Type = Void

So did why transaction actually failed? If so, why ? (or how can I find out why)

Answer (score 1):

Did you select on the "Void transaction when my server fails to receive data sent by the silent post" checkbox in the Hosted Checkout Page setting? If yes, then it indicates that silent post could not be sent successfully to the silent post URL. Transactions will be voided if there's error when receiving silent post message, even when the transaction is at first approved. You need to check the silent post receiver/processor that is located in the silent post URL to see if it works correctly. Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#silent-posts

By the way, you can uncheck the "void transaction" checkbox to allow transactions coming through even when silent post fails

Comment: In my test code, I got 2 URLs for silent post. (1) /sale/pay_confirm for silent post  (2) /sale/pay_error for silent post failure. Both URL's currently do the same minimal thing - print some logs and display a simple page.  Both URLs can accept arbitrary number of parameters. Both URLs can be accessed (tested with browser).   I even tried to interchange the URL in the paypal manager where /sale/pay_confirm was specified for silent post failure and was called with voided transaction.    So I am pretty sure /sale/pay_confirm  is working and accessible. Any idea why then silent post would fail?

Comment: I am getting the same error Mark; have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Hello Mark, I too have the same problem